# Alarm Button interacts incorrectly with view - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, button, swiftui, timer

I'm continuing to develop a timer app for practice purposes and have the basic functions ready so far.

The timer works in such a way that if you click on "Start" the timer simply runs down to 0 and then selects the next player - here you can also the button in the upper middle whether an alarm is played after the timer or not - however, this also stops the timer, although this does not occur in the implementation (see also video below). I hope someone can help me.

For the timer I made a `StopWatchManager` class:

```
import Foundation

class StopWatchManager : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var secondsElapsed : Double = 0.00
    @Published var mode : stopWatchMode = .stopped
    var timer : Timer = Timer()
    
    //Start the timer
    func start() -> Void {
        secondsElapsed = 0.00
        mode = .running
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true){ _ in
            self.secondsElapsed += 0.01
        }
    }
    
    //Pause the timer
    func pause() -> Void {
        timer.invalidate()
        mode = .paused
    }
    
    //Stop the timer
    func stop() -> Void {
        timer.invalidate()
        secondsElapsed = 0.00
        self.mode = .stopped
    }
}

enum stopWatchMode{
    case running
    case stopped
    case paused
}
```

Then I have an overview `TimerView` which implements some little details and connects the buttons with `TimerTextView`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimerView: View {
    
    @State private var alarmSoundOn : Bool = true
    @State private var quitGame : Bool = false
    
    //buttons variable for timer
    @State private var startTimer : Bool = false
    @State private var resetTimer : Bool = false
    @State private var pauseTimer : Bool = false
    @State private var quitTimer : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            TimerTextView(startTimer: $startTimer, resetTimer: $resetTimer, pauseTimer: $pauseTimer, quitTimer: $quitTimer, playAlarmSound: $alarmSoundOn)
            
            if (!quitGame) {
                VStack{
                    HStack(alignment: .top){
                        
                        //TODO - find bug with Timer
                        Button(action: {
                            alarmSoundOn.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            if (alarmSoundOn) {
                                Image(systemName: "speaker.circle")
                                    .resizable().frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            } else {
                                Image(systemName: "speaker.slash.circle")
                                    .resizable().frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            }
                        }).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    Spacer() 
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

And here is my `TimerTextView` where all the logic with the buttons and the circle happens:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct TimerTextView: View {
    
    //timer instance
    @ObservedObject var playTimer : StopWatchManager = StopWatchManager()
    
    //default buttons for the timer
    @Binding var startTimer : Bool
    @Binding var resetTimer : Bool
    @Binding var pauseTimer : Bool
    @Binding var quitTimer : Bool
    
    //variables for circle
    var timerSeconds : Int = 10
    @State private var progress : Double = 1.00
    @State private var endDate : Date? = nil
    
    //seconds of timer as text in the middle of the timer
    @State var textTimerSeconds : Double = 10
    
    //sound for the alarm after the timer exceeded
    @Binding var playAlarmSound : Bool
    @State private var playAlarmAtTheEnd : Bool = true
    let sound : SystemSoundID = 1304
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            if (quitTimer) {
                EmptyView()
            } else {
                
                //Circles---------------------------------------------------
                VStack{
                    VStack{
                        VStack{
                            ZStack{
                                //Circle
                                ZStack{
                                    
                                    Circle()
                                        .stroke(lineWidth: 20)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.3))
                                    
                                    Circle()
                                        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(Double(min(progress, 1.0))))
                                        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(270.0))
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .animation(.linear, value: progress)
                                }.padding()
                                
                                VStack{
                                    //Timer in the middle
                                    Text("\(Int(textTimerSeconds.rounded(.up)))")
                                        .font(.system(size: 80))
                                        .bold()
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                                
                            }.padding()
                            //timer responds every milliseconds and calls intern function decrease timer
                                .onReceive(playTimer.$secondsElapsed, perform: { _ in
                                    decreaseTimer()
                                })
                            //pauses the timer
                                .onChange(of: pauseTimer, perform: { change in
                                    if (pauseTimer) {
                                        playTimer.pause()
                                    } else {
                                        endDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(textTimerSeconds))
                                        playTimer.start()
                                    }
                                })
                            //resets the timer
                                .onChange(of: resetTimer, perform: { change in
                                    if (resetTimer) {
                                        resetTimerToBegin()
                                        resetTimer = false
                                    }
                                })
                            //play alarm sound at the end of the timer
                                .onChange(of: playAlarmSound, perform: { change in
                                    if (playAlarmSound){
                                        playAlarmAtTheEnd = true
                                    } else {
                                        playAlarmAtTheEnd = false
                                    }
                                })
                                .onChange(of: startTimer, perform: { change in                                    startTimerFromBegin()
                                })
                        }
                    }.foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    
                    
                    //----------------- Buttons
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 50){
                        
                        //if isStoped -> show play, reset & quit
                        //if !isStoped -> show pause
                        if(pauseTimer){
                            
                            HStack(alignment: .bottom){
                                
                                Spacer()
                                Spacer()
                                
                                //Play Button
                                Button(action: {
                                    pauseTimer = false
                                }, label: {
                                    VStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 5){
                                        Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                                        Text("Play").font(.callout)
                                    }
                                })
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    .padding(3.0)
                                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                //Reset Button
                                Button(action: {
                                    resetTimer = true
                                }, label: {
                                    VStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 5){
                                        Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                                        Text("Reset").font(.callout)
                                    }
                                })
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    .padding(3.0)
                                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                //Quit Button
                                Button(action: {
                                    quitTimer = true
                                }, label: {
                                    VStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 5){
                                        Image(systemName: "flag.fill")
                                        Text("Exit").font(.callout)
                                    }
                                })
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    .padding(3.0)
                                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                                
                                Spacer()
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        } else if (startTimer) {
                            
                            //Pause Button
                            Button(action: {
                                pauseTimer = true
                            }, label: {
                                VStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 5){
                                    Image(systemName: "pause.fill")
                                    Text("Pause").font(.callout)
                                }
                            })
                                .font(.title2)
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .padding(3.0)
                                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                            
                        } else {
                            
                            //Play Button
                            Button(action: {
                                pauseTimer = false
                                startTimer = true
                            }, label: {
                                VStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 5){
                                    Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                                    Text("Start").font(.callout)
                                }
                            })
                                .font(.title2)
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                                .padding(3.0)
                                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //FUNCTIONS --------------------------------
    
    private func startTimerFromBegin() -> Void{
        endDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(timerSeconds))
        playTimer.start()
    }
    
    private func resetTimerToBegin() -> Void {
        endDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(timerSeconds))
        progress = 1.0
        textTimerSeconds = Double(timerSeconds)
    }
    
    private func decreaseTimer() -> Void{
        guard let endDate = endDate else { print("decreaseTimer() was returned"); return }
        progress = max(0, endDate.timeIntervalSinceNow / TimeInterval(timerSeconds))
        textTimerSeconds -= 0.01
        if endDate.timeIntervalSinceNow <= 0 {
            if (playAlarmAtTheEnd) {
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(sound)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating your `playTimer` in the subview ... That will reset it when the view is redrawn. Instead you should do this in the parent view and pass it down.

Also you should use `@StateObject` to instantiate.

```
struct TimerView: View {
    
    //timer instance HERE
    @StateObject var playTimer : StopWatchManager = StopWatchManager()
    ...
```

pass down to subview

```
        // pass timer here
        TimerTextView(playTimer: playTimer, startTimer: $startTimer, resetTimer: $resetTimer, pauseTimer: $pauseTimer, quitTimer: $quitTimer, playAlarmSound: $alarmSoundOn)
```

Subview:

```
struct TimerTextView: View {
    
    //passed timer
    @ObservedObject var playTimer : StopWatchManager
    ...
```

One more thing: Firing the timer every 0.01 seconds is too much. You should go to 0.1

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works the way it is supposed to... I will now more concentrate on main and subviews